# Linux: Need to retrieve list of files on server B from server A can not use PHP or KeyGen for SSH

Tags: mysql, linux, perl, ssh, ftp

I need to retrieve a list of *.zip files from server B which is an FTP server to server A (from server A) which is a mysql server. I am unable to use PHP or KeyGen for SSH without password. I am very limited on what I can do. I started trying to create a Perl Script to allow ssh log in without password but the dependencies just keep staking up, the network is not able to connect to the internet for updates, and I can not install in the default folder on the mysql or ftp server due to lack of permissions once I leave my ~ home directory.

The following bash script does exactly what I want however I can not use it in production because I can not generate a ssh-rsa/dsa-auth key that would allow ssh without a password. Any thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
`##Check tmp for previous listing

   fileExists=$(ls /tmp | grep file | wc -l);

 ## File should not exist--- Just incase we will check and remove it 
   if [ $fileExists = "1" ]; then

      rm /tmp/File.tmp

   fi

   ssh usr@100.0.0.0 ls | grep .zip >> /tmp/File.tmp

   echo "File list recieved sucessfully $DATE" >> ./logs/fileList.log
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance you may be able to give me.

Comment: Please shorten your title and make sure it makes sense, currently, it doesn't.

Comment: Same with your first sentence... you have two 'from's and no 'to'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) can do this quickly if your not squeamish about your username and password showing up in the process list

```
lftp -u username,password sftp://server -e "ls"
```

It also can run a whole series of commands from a file (with the -f switch), so the username and password don't show up.  It should be present on most linux boxes.

Comment: Thank you Charles! I am not the least bit squeamish and I can definately work with what you have given me.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is probably not what you want, but i do not see any other way than using `Net::SSH::Expect`with perl. I find it likely that you've already tried that one. If you get the dependencies sorted out, this should get you started:

**Disclaimer:** Untested, but a rewrite of some functioning code i had for some other stuff

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::SSH::Expect;


# Remove that file you didn't want in /tmp
if (-e '/tmp/File.tmp') { unlink('/tmp/File.tmp') }

# These should be obvious
my $username = 'bob';
my $password = 'bobsecretpassword';
my $targethosts = '100.0.0.0';

print "Trying $host... ";
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
  host      => $host,
  user      => $username,
  password  => $password,
) or die "Couldn't create SSH client\n";

$ssh->run_ssh() or die "Couldn't run SSH client\n";

my $output = $ssh->exec("ls *.zip");

open LOG,">>./logs/fileList.log"

my $timestamp = time();    # !!!! You probably want a better sollution for a timestamp than this
print LOG "$timestamp\tFile list received OK\n";

# Cleanup time... not a whole lot to do, tho
$ssh->close();
close LOG;

__END__
```

**As for the dependency problem**, I'm afraid i can't be of much help other than hoping cpan sorts it out for you, as that's normally what it does for me: `cpan -i Net::SSH::Expect`

After (hopefully) getting the module installed for your user only, you will probably need to tell perl to add your personal modules directory into @INC, but that's beyond the scope of this post (google should take too long anyways).

Alternatively, bribe the sysadmin and have him/her install it systemwide.

Comment: Thank you for responding Jarmund,

Comment: Thank you for responding Jarmund: This is my first question posted so please bare with me on figuring out how to post... I spent the first 7 hours of the day trying to install all of the dependencies for `Net::SSH::Expect` using `perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~/mydir/lib LIB=~/mydir/lib` in an attempt to get past my administrative limitations and it seems like every time I install something I have another dependancie or the lib trys installing to a directory I do not have privellages for.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes in my post Markus. Let me know if you think I shared clearify anything else.

Comment: Net::SSH::Expect is not completely reliable. [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SSH2) or [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH) are better options for automating SSH tasks in Perl.

Comment: @salva Thanks. Note to self: Rewrite my own stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(host => '...', user => '...', password => '...');
$sftp->setcwd('...');
$sftp->mget('*.zip');
```